# Allow embedded Images in HTMpurifier

Tags: wysiwyg, htmlpurifier

I have wysiwyg editor and filtered using htmlpurifier, Id like to allow the users to directly drop or paste images in the editor and the image is saved as textformat, but the htmlpurifier filter this out, how to configure htmlpurifier to allow embedded images?

Comment: If you're using it for general images (bigger than a few Kb) then you should save them as separate files instead of using them inline: http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2011/why-inlining-everything-is-not-the-answer/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the editor is doing the embedding, but if it is embedding them as data URLs, you can enable it modifying %URI.AllowedSchemes to include 'data'.